# HTPC and backing up DVDs, where to start?

Tags: dvd, htpc, video-streaming, backup

So this is pretty much two different questions, I just didnt want to make too many threads.

1) I decided I want to start backing up my DVD(and even Bluray). Does anyone know of any great tools that will keep the original quality, and allow me to be able to stream them to my TV? (which leads to question 2)

2) I'm planning on getting cable in a few months, and figured I'd just build an HTPC and use Windows 7. Would this setup allow me to stream media from my PC and Mac? Or would I have to get AppleTV or something similar instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows media center - this plugin will help you with ripping DVDs etc. It works from within windows media center: [auto rip n compress (image below)](http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/t/81697.aspx?PageIndex=1). If you just want to rip from a desktop application, I suggest handbrake which is free

[image]

As for streaming - what are you trying to stream to? your cable box? If you build a HTPC, you can store the DVDs on there, or stream them from a network location such as another computer or NAS or even an external hard drive. Just connect your HTPC to your TV with a DVI/HDMI cable and you're away

Answer (score 1):

1) [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is so easy. I really don't see why people bother making programs that do less. Set the RF (Quality) to somewhere around 19-22, 23 on Godfather 1 made a 2gb file that was just over 1000 pixels high. You can move it around and see the resolution, and even use the preview window. [Here's their wiki on it](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/ConstantQuality).

2) Apple TV would be cheaper, though it can't play 1080p. Using it with 720p and your TV's upscaler is a good and common option, it's also cheaper than a HTPC and just simpler. Only consider a Windows (in any room tbh) if you are tied down to something on Windows.